# Hole Size Constraint Violation on DRC Check for custom mounting holes

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication, mounting-holes

It is about Altium designer. I am fairly new to that platform please bear with me.

I am at the stage finalizing PCB for manufacturing. Of course, I have to deal with couple of DRC errors and warnings. But, one of them is not that clear to me.

I have created a mounting hole library using `Pad` and `drill size in 3.4mm diameter and hole size 5mm with plated option`.

DRC is now complaining about the drill size `can't be bigger than 2.54mm`.
I can understand that, fine.

But, what would be the way to create this hole with plated option then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit the drill size rule to increase the maximum size, AD has a rather silly default here.

This is pretty much a standard change when configuring AD.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so in the first place but then hesitated to do it so. Because, what if it is part of `*.PcbDoc` of my manufacturer. 
Can we then say it is irrelevant?

Comment: What does your manufacturer say about maximum drill size? Put that value in there, also min drill size and minimum annular ring, for more often a problem.

Comment: It is not mentioned particularly as far as I could read the document. But, minimum is about 0.35mm. So, there shouldn't be any issue then. 
I have re-run the DRC with increased hole size and the violation error has disappeared. 
Thank you for your prompt answers Dan.

Comment: Must be a very low cost fab, 0.3mm is a standard sort of cheap fab minimum (Note that you always talk about finished hole sizes by default), and 0.2mm is fairly commonplace. At the large end they usually top out at about 5mm or so, then switch to milling.